# Views get OG mixed information

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups

Im trying to create a view that will get the following:

```
Organic group: Name.
Organic group: Members.
Organic group: Number of published nodes.
```

Its sounds like an easy task but really it isnt.
I got really confused with the type of view, and theres much relationships to be done, And after adding aggregation the view gets huge and frustrating.

I was thinking about creating each one as a separated view and embedding them on a page, but that might sound bad.

**UPDATE**
here is whats expected of the view to produce.

```
Organic group: Group A.
Organic group: X, Y, Z.
Organic group: 3 open tasks.

Organic group: Group Alpha.
Organic group: Alpha, Beta, Gamma.
Organic group: 0 Open tasks.

Organic group: Power rangers.
Organic group: Green dude, White dude.
Organic group: 15 open tasks.
```

Tasks being the content type that belongs to an OG.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Number of published node in particular group only ?

Comment: @mohit_rocks Yes, I updated the question to give and example. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [Organic group](http://drupal.org/project/og) module. So this module also provides two views called **Og members** and **Og Content**. Now download the module [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) which allows you to embed views as field in other view. See the Readme.txt file for more detail.

Create a new view and embed other two views **Og members** and **Og Content** in new view.

Comment: My thoughts pretty much. I think that Views Field View would be an unavoidable requirement for what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @magtak you are right, I have worked on it, but today i don't have views code otherwise i would have straight away paste over here :-)